# How to change UserRepresentation of keycloak REST API response?

Tags: typescript, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

When we do a **GET** request to URL:

```
https://my-keycloak/admin/realms/test-realm/users
```

We get a list of all users that belongs to `test-realm`.

From Keycloak REST API documentation, this response is typped as ["UserRepresentation"](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/18.0/rest-api/#_userrepresentation) (last session of the wiki page):
[definition of response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTugu.png)

But, i have only receive responses with this attributes:

```
export interface KeycloakUserRepresentation {
  id: string;
  createdTimestamp: number;
  username: string;
  enabled: boolean;
  totp: boolean;
  emailVerified: boolean;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  email: string;
  disableableCredentialTypes: [];
  requiredActions: string[];
  notBefore: number;
  access: {
    manageGroupMembership: boolean;
    view: boolean;
    mapRoles: boolean;
    impersonate: boolean;
    manage: boolean;
  };
}
```

And I need to force Keycloak to append the `clientRoles` optional attribute inside this response. What do I need to do to enforce it?

I have tested adding role mappings and groups to users to see if the response changes, but nothing changed.
The only thing that provokes a change in response is adding the user attribute to User manually. But the clientRoles is the attribute that I want to show.

Comment: No way, you can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to get the optional attributes of the UserRepresentation but you can have the client role for a given user with the *users/{id}/role-mappings* endpoint. It'll return something like this:

```
{
"realmMappings": [
    {
        "id": "aaff6fd4-674f-4f7b-888d-c4ebed655d52",
        "name": "default-roles-master",
        "description": "${role_default-roles}",
        "composite": true,
        "clientRole": false,
        "containerId": "master"
    }
],
"clientMappings": {
    "test_client": {
        "id": "e490adbe-3b9f-4c40-ad0f-c90847193c11",
        "client": "test_client",
        "mappings": [
            {
                "id": "c31189f4-763c-45ac-a4a0-fa12ffc02832",
                "name": "Test role",
                "composite": false,
                "clientRole": true,
                "containerId": "e490adbe-3b9f-4c40-ad0f-c90847193c11"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

Documentation (22.0.4): https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/22.0.4/rest-api/index.html#_role_mapper

I checked the administration console calls to the API and it gets no more that what you have as a UserRepresentation